# how to select one TableViewCell and set all the other Cells to the Bool Value NO in CoreData?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, uitableview, tableview

i have a list of tables,saved in core data with a bool value, when i select a cell the bool value is saved to YES in core data. but when i select one more than one Cell, 2 cells are on YES. i just want to set 1 cell to be yes. how can i do that. 
here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BestuhlungCell *cell =(BestuhlungCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];


    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.bestuhlungLabel.text = [managedObject valueForKey:@"bestuhlungstitel"];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[managedObject valueForKey:@"bestuhlungsfoto"]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    cell.bestuhlungFoto.image = image;
    cell.checkButton.hidden=YES;


    return cell;

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [app managedObjectContext];
  //  BestuhlungCell *cell = (BestuhlungCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    Bestuhlung *bestuhlung=[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];







    if ([[bestuhlung valueForKey:@"check"] boolValue]) {
        [bestuhlung setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"check"];

    } else {

        [bestuhlung setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"check"];

    }


    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }



    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something along the lines:

```
NSArray *sections = self.fetchedResultsController.sections;
for(NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo *sectionInfo in sections) {
  for(Bestuhlung *currentBestuhlung in sectionInfo.objects {
    if(currentBestuhlung == bestuhlung) {
      // the selected bestuhlung
      if ([[bestuhlung valueForKey:@"check"] boolValue]) 
        [bestuhlung setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"check"];
      else 
        [bestuhlung setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"check"];
    }
    else {
      // those are the other ones you want to uncheck
      [currentBestuhlung setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"check"];
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: it worked i just have to correct your second line to this :for(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo in sections)

Comment: ..ups my bad, just wrote it off the top of my head :-)

Comment: i found a bug. when i select a cell and go back to my main view, the other cells from another view selects accidantly a cell. i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

As it is clear from your snippet that you are only modifying the value of selected cell but not for other table values.

In order to achieve this, you have set the BOOL value to NO for every row in the table then you can proceed with the same line of code.